# What defines a "Well recieved question"?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was looking at the badges and I saw the "Curious", "Inquisitive" and "Socratic" badges;

> Asked a well-received question on (x) separate days, and maintained a positive question record

What defines a "well-received question", and what defines a "positive question record"?

Comment: Pretty sure it just means "positively scored question"

Comment: @Unionhawk He's not asking what it is, but what the definition exactly is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read the full description of the badges [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/13992).

---

A well received question has a positive score, isn't closed and isn't deleted.

In order to maintain a positive question record:

- For every question with a score of 0 or worse, you need to have a well received question.
- For every closed question of yours, you need to have a well received question.
- For every deleted question of yours, you need to have a well received question.

To be clear, if your question is non-positively scored, closed *and* deleted then you need *three* well-received questions to make up for it.

In order to count for the "well-received question on X separate days" criterion, you need to ask at least one well-received question and *no* non-well-received question on X separate days.

Comment: What about questions you deleted? Do they still contribute to the counter?

Comment: @Ben It seems that they count as a non-well-received question.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the clarification :)